# Generic failure when sending sms in some mobiles

Tags: android, mobile, sms, smsmanager

I am trying to send a SMS which is less than 160 characters using generally available code. But for some mobiles I am getting generic failure. I have given all sms read/write permissions as well.I tried both ways- with and without country code for phone number but still getting the same error. Why I am getting this error? Below is the code.

```
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

            if(getResultCode()== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (getResultCode()== SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (getResultCode() == SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (getResultCode() == SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (getResultCode() == SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Unknown error!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);

    //ArrayList<String> texts = sms.divideMessage(message);
    //sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, texts, null, null);

}
```

Below are the permissions that I have given.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Possibly the radio log could give you some clues. See if SmsDispatcher and RIL prints anything interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Are those phones' API above or equal to 6.0.  If so you need to ask for permission explicitly/programatically.

Comment: @ScottS- I have already given all permissions from application manager. Do I still need to ask for permission everytime the application is launched?